# UIScrollView - How to reload data on second page of subview?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview, ios6

I have a scrollview that is set up to scroll back and forth between 2 pages.  Each page uses different data for labels, etc... on the same view controller.

I need to re-load the data on each page, without exiting the 'sub' view.

For example, I navigate to page 1 in the scroll view.  My web svc sends me updated data via notification.  I need to reload the data that is on page 2, while still sitting on page 1... or at least reload that data the instant I start scrolling to page 2.

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks in advance!

(snippet from my scrollView.. but I would think I need to add something in my subview..?)

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
if (page < 0) return;
if (page >= kNumberOfPages) return;

if ([controllerName isEqualToString:@"ClassicViewController"]){
    ClassicViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {

        controller = [[ClassicViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
        controller.referringObject = self.referringObject;
        controller.user = self.user;
        controller.pushedFromScroll = kTrue;
        controller.theirRoll = self.theirRoll;

         NSLog(@"page replaced # = %d", page);
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }


    if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options, but I think if your data is posting a notification that it's been updated, you should have the view controller for each page be responsible for updating the elements of their view. So -

1. Have each view controller subscribe to the notification you describe with `NSNotificationCenter`'s `addObserver:selector:name:objet` method.
2. Implement the notification handler whose selector you passed to `addObserver...` to update the view based on the changes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My issue is that I only have 1 view controller in my scroll view.  Both pages data gets loaded when the view is first brought up.  I need to 'refresh' the data for this view controller's correct page.  Meaning, if 'player 2' gets updated, then their data on page 2 reflects that.  I'm having trouble updating a certain pages data from within the view controller.

Comment: @mtb your code instantiates a separate `ClassicViewController` for what looks like every page of a scroll view. Can you update your question to show the view controller responsible for updating the two pages, and could you also describe particularly the trouble you're having? I can take a look and try to post another answer later today. EDIT: yes I see in your first line you say there's one view controller, I'm not sure I see how the code jives with that. So I'd like to help but don't think I have information to do so at this time. I'll watch this question for updates though.

Comment: Thanks Carl.. I ended up creating separate view controllers and doing as you suggested.